# Using TypeScript for Wakanda server side scripts

Tags: typescript, wakanda

I created a small test project using TypeScript serverside on Wakanda so I can use the advantage of TypeScript on the client and the server. So far everything works nicely.

- Can anybody think of some sort of issue I could run into at a later point doing this?
- Are there any TypeScript type definitions available for wakanda server?

Comment: There are no official typings but it would be cool to share them with the community. I suggest you to post your example once you have finished since it can be very instructive. Good job!

Comment: Here my sample solution that i started working on. But how would i correctly declare the DataModel and DataStore? I'm kind of lost here ... https://github.com/steeu/wakanda-typescript. Most of the typings I took from https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-api-reference ... any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Oh great, you can stick on those typings then. They seem pretty complete to me. How are you struck on the DataModel and DataStore?

Answer (score 0):

@stefan, Nice idea ! Glad you started working from the wakanda-reference-api because we 're currently hardly working on it to make it more efficient. (if you cloned the githup repo, we can access the d.ts model/datastore api, even it's not available on the html files)